# Quick control dial problem on Canon EOS 7D

Tags: canon-7d

When I turn the quick control dial, nothing happens anymore. This problem has appeared suddenly ...

Just would like to know if you guys have also experienced this problem.

It is possible to open the canon (it's not under warranty anymore) to clean the surface below the dial and remount it ?

**EDIT :**

similar problems below :

https://www.google.fr/search?q=canon+7d+quick+dial+prlblem&sugexp=chrome,mod=5&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

**EDIT 2 :**

The insidious Lock button is on the right position !

Comment: Believe it or not, this is one of the most common questions I get from xxD and xD owners. At least they made the Lock less subtle on the 7D!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have the Lock switch (located below the Quick Dial Wheel) set in the "off" position, lined up with the white line on the back.

[image]

Comment: I should have mentioned it : the Lock is on the right position ! :)

Comment: It needs to be on the left position! ;-)